# Is it possible to use a MySQL field value in the WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building an Insurance Quoting system and have a number of questions to ask. My questions are stored in one table (questionsTable), my answers are stored in the answers's table (answersTable) and the question/answer action (i.e., whether to refer the quote or prompt another question) is stored in the actions table (actionsTable).

Here's some sample data

questionsTable

```
    questionId | questionDescription
    1          | What percentage of the roof is flat?
    2          | Please provide details of the roof construction:
    3          | How many rooms does the building have?
```

answersTable

```
    answerId | questionId | answerValue
    1        | 1          | < 50%
    2        | 1          | > 50%
    3        | 2          | freeForm
    4        | 3          | 1
    5        | 3          | 2
    6        | 3          | 3
    7        | 3          | 3+
```

actionsTable

```
    actionId | answerId | action
    1        | 2        | 2
    2        | 6        | refer
    3        | 7        | decline
```

The way the tables link is this:
Each question has answers, selectable from the database certain answers carry certain actions - ask another question, or decline the quote. If they are to ask another question, the id of the question is stored in the action field.

So basically, if you answer '>50%' to question 1 'What percentage of the roof is flat?' you get given question 2 to answer.

My question is, how can I select all the questions from the 'questionsTable' WHERE the ID is not equal to any of the 'action' values from the 'actionsTable' - Thus giving me the 'top-level' question set?

I know I could do this simply in PHP using two MySQL queries, 1 to select all the numeric values from the 'actionsTable', then another to select the questions

`'SELECT questionDescription 
    FROM questionsTable

WHERE questionsTable.questionId != 'this' AND questionsTable.questionId != 'this', etc`

The design of this database is to be normalised but also dynamic, e.g. the management team can use admin pages to add/remove questions, answers and actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT questionDescription FROM questionsTable
LEFT JOIN actionsTable ON questionsTable.questionId=actionsTable.action
WHERE actionsTable.action IS NULL
```

This joins the two, preserving all values in questionsTable, and only showing ones where there is no match in actionsTable on the action field.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: LEFT JOIN has all rows of the "left" (first) table no matter what.  They are joined with matching rows of other table if those rows exist, otherwise those fields are NULL (exactly what you're looking for)

Comment: Seems so simple now it's explained. We were using the answersTable and over complicating things.

Comment: Glad it helped. Sorry I couldn't explain more, I was occupied. Thanks @jon_darkstar for helping clarify.